# how to read from a particular line upto a particular line in python

Tags: python, parsing

I haave a file and I want to read a specific part of it. This is the file.

.....
.....
Admin server interface begins
...
....
....
....
....
Admin server interface ends
....
....

I want to read the part of file between 'admin server interface begins' till 'admin server interface ends'. I found a way of doing it in perl but can't find a way in python.

in perl

```
while (<INP>)
{
  print $_ if(/^AdminServer interface definitions begins/ .. /^AdminServer interface definitions ends/);
}
```

Could anyonle please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file line by line and gather what is in between your markers.

```
def dispatch(inputfile):
    # if the separator lines must be included, set to True
    need_separator = True
    new = False
    rec = []
    with open(inputfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            if "Admin server interface begins" in line:
                new = True
                if need_separator:
                    rec = [line]
                else:
                    rec = []
            elif "Admin server interface ends" in line:
                if need_separator:
                    rec.append(line)
                new = False
                # if you do not need to process further, uncomment the following line
                #return ''.join(rec)
            elif new:
                rec.append(line)
    return ''.join(rec)
```

The code above will successfully return data even if the input file does not contain the ending separator (`Admin server interface ends`). You can amend the last `return` with a condition if you want to catch such files:

```
if new:
    # handle the case where there is no end separator
    print("Error in input file: no ending separator")
    return ''
else:
    return ''.join(rec)
```

Comment: You probably want `Admin server interface ends` on the `elif` part.

Comment: @user3267581: yes, I was too quick typing, thanks. Corrected.

Comment: you should also break out of the loop in the `elif "Admin server interface ends" in line:` block, since OP doesn't need the rest of the file

Comment: @oxymor0n: true. I left that part open to allow for expansion (I use something like this to break a file into several pieces delimited by a string). I will comment to strictly adhere to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't very big and you are not concerned about memory consumption, you can write this simple solution:

```
from os.path import isfile
def collect_admin_server_interface_info(filename):
    """ Collects admin server interface information from specified file. """
    if isfile(filename):
        contents = ''
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            contents = file.read()
        beg_str = 'Admin server interface begins'
        end_str = 'Admin server interface ends'
        beg_index = contents.find(beg_str + len(beg_str))
        end_index = contents.find(end_str)
        if beg_index == -1 or end_index == -1:
             raise("Admin server interface not found.")
        return contents[beg_index : end_index]
    else:
        raise("File doesn't exist.")
```

This method will try to return a single string containing administrator server interface information.